# How can I position the bootstrap carousel item captions outside of the image without manually defining a height on the carousel?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

```html
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" className="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
      <div className="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" className="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
   
      <div className="carousel-inner">
        <div className="carousel-item active">
           <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
           <div>
            Captions
           </div>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-item">
           <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button className="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

This is a standard bootstrap carousel that I have. What I wanna do now is to position the `Captions` that are going to be inside each `carousel-item`, outside of the `carousel-item` and `carousel-inner`, but within the `carousel` container. I want them to be beneath the `indicators`, and to slide with each `carousel-item`.

Here's an image of where I want the captions to be:

[Captions outside of the item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lpSD.png)

I can obviously use position absolute, but then the height of the `carousel` will not expand, I have to expand it myself, and I don't wanna do that. What other ways can you think of moving them outside of the image, beneath the `indicators`, but still to slide with each `carousel-item`?

Why is it that when I add padding-top or margin-top to the caption element, the `indicators` move down with it?

[padding or margin on the caption element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmvky.png)

Comment: Just don't position them absolute then, but leave them in normal flow?

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean? If the caption element is inside the `carousel-item`, then it will be inside the image. If I place the element outside of the `carousel-item`, then it will not slide. If I use `position:relative`, it will not expand the height. What do I do?

Comment: If you use `relative`, then `left`, `right` and `bottom` still apply - so you should either set those all to `auto`, or go with `position: static` instead. Simply disabling `position: absolute` via dev tools (and the white text color as well), is enough to make that work perfectly fine for me with the example under https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#with-captions

Comment: Oh, the indicators go down at the same time then, because they are absolutely positioned at the bottom of the container as well. You'd have to place those a bit higher up then, increase the `bottom` value.

Comment: @CBroe I don't understand what you mean. If I use `static`, then `top`, `bottom` etc. don't work. If I use `relative`, then then making it `bottom: -50px` for instance will not expand the container, it will overflow and get hidden.

Comment: _"If I use static, then top, bottom etc. don't work"_ - yes, and why should they? The caption will then automatically go under the image, so why would you _need_ those to work any more?

Comment: @CBroe Why do they go beneath the image? Also, why when I use padding-top or margin-top on the caption to push it a bit down, the `indicators` move down with it? 
I have updated the question to include the image.

Comment: _"Why do they go beneath the image?"_ - because they come after the image in the DOM - so _what else_ should they do, if you don't apply any positioning? _"... the indicators move down with it?"_ - as I already said, those are still positioned absolute - in regard to the outer container `.carousel`, and that container has grown now, _because_ you put the captions below the images.

Comment: @CBroe I am trying to move the indicators up, but I can't find them in the sass file. This is the only class that targets them: https://imgur.com/a/vaO3oqq When I inspect the indicators from inspect tools of the browser, I see another `carousel_indicators` class applied to them with position absolute on them, but on the actual sass file, I don't see that class. How come?

Comment: With the original BS5 example, the formatting clearly all comes from the `carousel-indicators` class. _"I see another `carousel_indicators` class applied to them"_ - then yours must have a different class, than what you have shown us above. There is no way that `carousel_indicators` applies to anything, if the code only contains a different class name, `carousel-indicators`. I don't know why or how your BS differs from the original.

Comment: @CBroe No worries, I already fixed it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @new_employee what was the solution to your problem?

Comment: @LajosArpad I just removed the position directions, top/right/left/bottom, and only left it with `position: relative`, and then used `margin-top` to move it down a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply removing Bootstrap's `carousel-caption` class solves the issue. You can use the `position-relative` class as a replacement on your caption div.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x200/000/fff" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="position-relative text-center">
          Caption 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x200/000/fff" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="position-relative text-center">
          Caption 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x200/000/fff" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="position-relative text-center">
          Caption 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I never had `carousel-caption` class applied in my example. Why does applying `position-relative` without any `top` or `bottom`s positions the element beneath the `indicators`? Also, why is it that when I use `margin-top` or `padding-top` to push down the captions, the `indicators` get dragged with it too?

Comment: @new_employee Not sure. You will have to look into creating an [example] in your question. My snippet is your code with dummy images and is working as expected. I cannot see whatever you are seeing so please update your question so your code shows precisely your problem.

Comment: You said simply removing the `carousel-caption` class solves the issue. But I never had a `carousel-caption` class applied in my example. Also, if you add `mt-5` or `pt-5` to the caption element, next to `position-relative text-center`, would the `indicators` not get moved down too?

Comment: I have updated the question to include an image of what happens when I add padding-top to the caption element.

Comment: @new_employee Does this help? [A Fiddle for new_employee](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/xhp24a6b/4/)